# TimeInput Format Validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a template with an input field. The input field uses a timepicker plugin which uses a format like "1:00 AM" or "4:30 PM".

In forms.py, ive tried:

`timepicker = forms.TimeField(label='Time', widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M %p'`))
`timepicker = forms.TimeField(label='Time', widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%I:%M %p'`))

But with both these snippets, i continue to get a input validation error that says it does not match the format.

Comment: You are using %I in one place and %H in the other.  I think one is 12 hour, the other is 24 hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
forms.TimeField(label='time',
                input_formats=['%I:%M %p'], 
                widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%I:%M %p'))
```